# How can I check if a char is in the alphabet?

Tags: livecode

I've been researching the keyDown operator and I can't seem to find anywhere if its possible to write a program with `on keyDown key` without having to deal with non alphabetic chars. Hopefully someone with a bit more experience could let me know how to do this!

Comment: Please, stop including tags in the title. Only write the question, don't include additional information such as the programming language or the operating system.

Comment: When people answer your question, please give feed-back in the comments or by voting up their answers.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I only just became able to upvote (yes, I'm that much of a noob on this site, haha). I really do appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1):

To check that the parameter of the keyDown message contains a letter, check the ASCII value:

```
if (charToNum(theKey) >= 97 and charToNum(theKey) <= 122) and (charToNum(theKey) >= 65 and charToNum(theKey) <= 90) then
```

or use the `matchText()` function:

```
if matchText(theKey,"[a-zA-Z]") then
```